# django: pass an element to my template through context dictionary

Tags: django

in this view ...

```
def home(request):
    context = {'page_title':'Volunteers', 'action':'<button class="btn btn-primary btn-small">Leave</button>'}
    return render(request, 'app/home.html', context)
```

I try to send a button element (or some other HTML) through the context dictionary.
I add it to the template like this

```
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-6"><h4>{{page_title}}</h4></div>
        <div class="col-md-6 text-md-right mt-1">{{action}}</div>
    </div>
```

When the page renders, it just shows the text and does not allow it to be HTML.
[image: View]

Any idea how I can get this to treat it as HTML?

Thanks, Django beginner here finally coming from the dark side (PHP) =)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Mark the string as [HTML-safe](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/ref/templates/builtins/#safe):

```
{{page_title | safe}}
```

More about automatic HTML escaping in Django can be found [here](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/ref/templates/language/#automatic-html-escaping).

However, I would prefer another solution, where the button is described in the template, and conditionally rendered if needed, if it is one of small number of possible actions and they are all in the one place. If the buttons are required in multiple places, I would go with a custom Django template tag. Sending HTML from business code usually violates the principle of separation of code and presentation.

Answer (score 1):

In your view you can use **[mark_safe](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/utils/#django.utils.safestring.mark_safe)** method:

```
from django.utils.safestring import mark_safe

def home(request):
    context = {
        'page_title': 'Volunteers',
        'action': mark_safe('<button class="btn btn-primary btn-small">Leave</button>')
    }
    return render(request, 'app/home.html', context)
```

Comment: Thanks.  Your answer is great and it worked but it seemed easier to use {{page_title | safe}} in the template and I don't have to import anything...  That is why I accepted the other answer.

Comment: @TimB, thanks for the clarifications. it's ok ✅ .